# Присваивать новое значение переменной при каждом вызове

Tags: javascript

Есть одна переменная, которая постоянно меняется, допустим переменная А. Нужно сделать так, чтобы была вторая переменная, допустим Б, которая всегда бы соответствовала А. Если сделать Б = А, то Б фиксируется на момент присвоения и на новые изменения А не реагирует, сохраняя своё значение. Если сделать так

```
function test() {
    return A;
};

var Б = test();
```

то опять же, переменная фиксируется при вызове функции. Как сделать, чтобы при обращении к переменной Б она выдавала актуальное значение А? При условии, что создать функцию и вызывать Б() нельзя. Нужно именно Б, без скобок.

Comment: По-моему, вы хотите странного. А зачем вам это нужно? Может быть проще решить исходную проблему другим путем, а не изобретать костыли?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для переменных в глобальном контексте, то вы можете использовать метод [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty). Этот метод позволяет, помимо прочего, задавать произвольные геттеры и сеттеры для полей объекта. В тоже время, все глобальные переменные в JavaScript это поля некого глобального объекта (для браузера это `window`). Таким образом, ваш код может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
var a = 'a test value';

Object.defineProperty(window, 'b', {
    get: function() {
        // Возвращаем актуальное содержимое перменной "a"
        return a;
    },
    set: function(value) {
        // Этот метод специально оставлен пустым, чтобы
        // игнорировать присваивания переменной "b"
    }
});
```

Обратите внимание, что метод `Object.defineProperty` доступен не во всех браузерах. Если говорить о IE, то этот код будет работать только для IE9+

**P.S.:**

Что-то мне подсказывает, что вы пытаетесь решить некую исходную задачу неверными средствами. Идея, которую вы хотите реализовать, попахивает магией и противоречит основным концепциям переменных. Скорее всего, вы скоро забудете о реализованной связи переменных и из-за этого столкнетесь с кучей проблем при отладке. Мне кажется, вам стоит еще раз подумать, действительно ли нужно связывать переменные таким образом.

Comment: Спасибо! Это работает. Касательно задачи. Есть функция в другом файле (Node.js). Можно конечно просто указать `адрес файла.метод`, но это будет не очень красиво, вот и захотелось улучшить код, присвоив методу переменную.

Answer (score -1):

Можно и так сделать

```
var a = "some value";

setInterval(function(){ b === a || (b = a); }, 0);
```

Данное решение будет работать везде. но может будет логичнее генерировать события, при изменении `a`, и в нужном месте просто на него подписываться?

Comment: JavaScript **однопоточный** язык. Поэтому, если вы в одном и том же потоке сначала присвоите значение переменной `b` а потом будете его считывать, то ваш код будет выполнен _после_ манипуляций с переменной (пруф: http://jsfiddle.net/jjc2prgy/). Ну и это жуткий костыль, потому и минусую.

Comment: Сама постановка такой задачи - жуткий костыль. Что уж говорить о решениях? Если нужно что бы одна переменная зеркалировала своё состояние в другую, зачем тогда её перезаписывать? Гораздо логичнее использовать её как `readonly`. Если речь идет об изменении её другим скриптом, то возникает вопрос будут ли эти скрипты работать последовательно или асинхронно? во втором случае мой вариант очень даже подходит

Comment: Еще раз: JavaScript **однопоточный** язык. Тот код (см. пруф линк), что я приводил выше как раз асинхронный и он не работает так, как вы от него ждете. `setInterval(... , 0)` все равно будет вызван не более одного раза за каждый оборот event-loop.

Comment: JavaScript **однопоточный** язык - да ладно?! серьёзно? а **web worker'ры** еще не изобрели? в любом случае, я что продлагаю создавать новые потоки?

Жуткий костыль это когда написано `b = "test"` а в следующей строке `alert(b)` мы видим `some value`.

[вот](http://jsfiddle.net/7o1vrg9a/) о чем я говорю

Comment: JavaScript **однопоточный** язык, да. Если не верите -- почитайте как устроен event-loop, например, в node.js. Спецификация WebWorkers **не является** частью языка, и ее реализации доступны не во всех окружениях (привет node.js), Она поддерживается браузерами, да и то не всеми (привет IE9). А код, который вы привели не удовлетворяет одному из критериев исходного вопроса: при присвоении значения переменной `b` ее связь с переменной `a` теряется до следующего `setInterval(..., 0)`. Вы можете сколько угодно говорить, что это костыль (и я с этим согласен), но ваш ответ не является верным.